# Why isn't crontab working for me? (Ubuntu 11.04)

Tags: ubuntu, crontab

I can't get the crontab jobs running. I've checked /var/log/syslog and the scheduled jobs aren't there. I've edited the jobs with

```
sudo crontab -e
```

so they are created for root.

This is how my jobs looks like:

```
15 0 * * * /opt/scripts/programs/maintenance profile web_sites_backup
30 0 */3 * * /opt/scripts/programs/maintenance profile web_server_backup 
01 0 * * 0,4 /opt/scripts/programs/maintenance profile full_backup
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: crap, I think I've figured it out, I forgot to run the script with bash :D so... any other mistake you see in my syntax?

Comment: You can stipulate the scripts need to run with bash with the shebang line: `#!/bin/bash` as the first line

Comment: Is cron running `ps auwx | grep cron` ?